# Spring-security AuthenticationEntryPoint in applicationContext

Tags: grails, spring-security

basically im getting an error based on this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [example.TestAuthFilterEntryPoint] to required type [org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint] for property 'authenticationEntryPoint': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
... 42 more
```

Basically im only implementing this class as a AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
import org.springframework.security.ui.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.AuthenticationException;
public class TestAuthFilterEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint,
    InitializingBean {...
```

Am i missing something in terms of how to "convert" this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface you should implement is in `org.springframework.security.web` package in Spring Security >= 3.0 (just as you have in error message), so it should be:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.AuthenticationException;
public class TestAuthFilterEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint,
    InitializingBean {
  // ...
```

Comment: Many thanks!, might you even know about this issue since it is quite similar.
Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] to required type [org.springframework.security.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: Just google for `AuthenticationManager`, first link is _AuthenticationManager (Spring Security 3.0.7.RELEASE API)_ and points to JavaDocs which contain class packages. This one is in `org.springframework.security.authentication`.